# Categorizing Columns in a Graph

Tags: r

I would like to separate my columns in my graph based on categories and have the categories as legends on the graph that are distinguished by different colors.

Fewer: "circulatory", "digestive", "EMI", "mental", "musculoskeletal", "neoplasm", "nervous", "poorly_defined", "skin"

NoSigDiff: "congenital", "external_cause", "genitourinary", "injury", "pregnancy_childbirth", "respiratory"

More: "infection"

Blood: "blood"

For example, the columns in the Fewer category can be colored blue and the columns in the NoSigDiff category can be colored red etc.

Here is the code I used to produce my graph
[image]

```
ggplot(Data,aes(diagnosis1, number_diagnoses))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.5)) +
   theme(axis.text.y=element_text(angle=90,hjust=0.5,vjust=0.5))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is difficult to answer without knowing what the "Data" dataframe contains, but try this:

```
library(tidyverse)

Data %>% 
  mutate(category = case_when(diagnosis %in% c("circulatory", "digestive", "EMI", "mental",
                                            "musculoskeletal", "neoplasm", "nervous",
                                            "poorly_defined", "skin") ~ "Fewer",
                              diagnosis %in% c("congenital", "external_cause",
                                                   "genitourinary","injury",
                                                   "pregnancy_childbirth",
                                                   "respiratory") ~ "NoSigDiff",
                              diagnosis == "infection" ~ "More",
                              diagnosis == "blood" ~ "Blood")) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = diagnosis1, y = number_diagnoses, fill = category))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.5)) +
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text(angle=90,hjust=0.5,vjust=0.5))
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you

Comment: No problem. In future questions, if possible, please post a small sample of your data to help us troubleshoot the issue, e.g. `dput(head(Data))` would allow me to test the code I wrote and see if it works, rather than just guessing.

Answer (score 2):

The way to do it would be adding a new column to your `Data` data.frame with the grouping variable. I am guessing that your data looks something like:

```r
  diagnosis1    number_diagnoses

1 blood          12000
2 circulatory    225000
...
```

If that's the case, you would have to create a vector with the labels that you want in the order of the `diagnosis1` column:

```r
color_labels = c("blood", "fewer", "NoSigDiff", ...)
```

and once you have it, append it to the data.frame with

```r
Data$categ = color_labels
```

and add the color information to the plot with

```r
ggplot(Data,aes(diagnosis1, number_diagnoses, fill=categ))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.5)) +
   theme(axis.text.y=element_text(angle=90,hjust=0.5,vjust=0.5))
```

Comment: So the data for diagnosis1 is setup in a column that is in relation to another column. So for example if the value of the other column is 30 then the value in diagnosis1 is blood and so on